# Laravel - save vs update

Tags: php, laravel, orm

I am wondering which one is a better solution for updating a database record - `addResources1` or `addresources2`?

First I tried the `update` query method since it looks clear to me. The second thought was, I was building models so lets use them and then just save.

What do you think?

There are several similar topics, however they say that `save()` will just insert a new record, in this case its not true.

ResourcesService:

```
 namespace App\Services;

 use App\Resource as Resource;
 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

 class ResourcesService
 {

     public function addResources1($userId, $wood, $stone, $food, $gold)
     {
         $resources = new Resource;
         $resources = $resources->where('userId', $userId)->update([
         'wood' => $wood,
         'stone' => $stone,
         'food' => $food,
         'gold' => $gold,
          ]);
      }

      public function addResources2($userId, $wood, $stone, $food, $gold)
      {
          $resources = new Resource;
          $resources = $resources->where('userId', $userId)->first();
          $resources->wood = $wood;
          $resources->stone = $stone;
          $resources->food = $food;
          $resources->gold = $gold;
          $resources->save();
      }
}
```

Resource model:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Resource extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'resources';

}
```

Answer (score 2):

This depends on your use case.

**1)** What will have the least amount of SQL queries?

Method `addResources1` will use 1 SQL query.

Method `addResources2` will use 2 SQL queries. One for fetching the record and the other for updating the record.

---

**2)** Is the model sensitive? (e.g. `is_admin` bool column)

If it does have sensitive column, you should not have that column put in the `fillable` property of the model and thus method `addResources1` will fail.

---

**3)** Do I need to do something else AFTER recording the updates but BEFORE committing to the database?

In this case, `addResources2` will better suit you since it wouldn't commit unless `save()` is executed and that's after all your other business logic is completed.

Answer (score 0):

[Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is better site of Stackexchange network for this kind of questions. If you are confident about what you are doing, first sample is ok. I am saying that because second example is going to update just one row in database even in case there is more rows with same value of `userId` column. If you know your structure first sample is more clear for see what does it do. Also, if you set relations between models you could chain it in a way

```
$user->resources()->update(['wood' => $wood, 'stone' => $stone, 'food' => $food, 'gold' => $gold,]);
```